# Api key for dashing dashboard

Tags: python, http-status-code-401, api-key, dashing

I'm working with the dashing.io dashboard and I want to make a post request with the requests lib in python to put data in a widget.

But it keeps sending me back a 401 error and an Invalid API Key. I don't understand why and don't really get the difference between the auth_token and the api key.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests



dashboard_url = "http://localhost:3030"
widget_id = 'my_widget_id'
widget_url = dashboard_url + '/widgets/my_widget_id'
data = {'name' : 'thomas','id' : 'bonjour','city' : 'cerfontaine'}
data = json.dumps(data)
headers ={'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept':'text/plain',
          'Authorization':'XYZ'}



try:
    r = requests.post(widget_url, data, headers=headers)
    print r.status_code
    print r.json()
    print r.text
except:
    r = requests.post(widget_url, data, headers=headers)
    print 'Dashing update failed'
    print r.text
```

My code auth_token in config.ru is XYZ too.
Can you guys help me ?

Comment: You're not sending the right API key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the key in your payload, not the header

```
data = {
    'name'       : 'thomas',
    'id'         : 'bonjour',
    'city'       : 'cerfontaine',
    'auth_token' : YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN_HERE
}
```

See my Django example [here](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/How-To:-update-dashboard-in-Django)